# Unexpected Characters in Resources.Designer.cs File

Tags: c#, wpf

I have no idea what happened. I opened my solution and now I get this weird errors in the Resources.Designer.cs file:

```
Unexpected Character "---" 
Unexpected Character "[]"
Unexpected Character """
....
...
..
..
```

When I open the Resources.Designer.cs file it has ASCII characters instead of the C# code. It is a WPF application using C# in VS 2013.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: By any chance, could encoding have been changed at some point in the past? Do you have any kind of version control system in place?

Comment: Doesn't sound like anything more than disk corruption.

Comment: I even got the latest version from TFS but it shows the same thing. I have not even checked in the code. I am not sure what it is?